# What methods are there for using an encrypted database to perform logging that is legally and forensically trustworthy?

Tags: databases, forensics, legal, logging

I am researching logging in a way that it could be used legally and also forensically trustworthy.  I have seen discussions about remote logging, hash chaining, timestamp chaining, write-once media.  My question is, Is it a viable solution to use an encrypted database, with similar techniques?  If so, are there any points that make this more attractive an option security wise?

Comment: There is a cryptographic technique called a Merkle Tree. I don't know the details, but some info [here](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/log-proofs-work). This is probably more of theoretical interest that something you want to implement in production.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can see. An encrypted database is (partially) protected against outside attackers. For your logs to be forensically acceptable, they need to be protected from modification by you and your system administrators who have full authorised access, and since you'll have the keys to your encrypted database, the encryption doesn't help with that.

Comment: `For your logs to be forensically acceptable, they need to be protected from modification by you and your system administrators who have full authorised access` - that rules out **all** log files since sysadmins have root access.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can buy forensically certified write-once media that your sysadmins can't overwrite, or you can immediately ship your logs off-site to a third party who doesn't let you modify them.

Comment: Not familiar with the write-once option, however in this context root access could still manipulate logs before they're shipped off the system.

Comment: As an alternative to write-only media, it is sometimes also possible to assert that the data hasn't been tampered by periodically publishing the hash of your database (or the head of the hash chain) into a public and widely distributed system, like as blockchain message in Bitcoin or a physical newspaper.

Comment: @user2320464 Not if the write-once media is mounted as the log drive and the logs are written directly to it.

Comment: Wouldn't write-once media still be susceptible to tampering by root before being written? Inserting a file system driver or tampering with the process.

Comment: @user2320464 One of the requirements for PCI certification (for example) is that all root activity is logged. So if a root user takes any action like that to corrupt future logs, it will be logged undeletably. And they can't make a change to prevent the change they've made from being logged, because it's too late by that point.